# Why this.state is not working in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs.I tried a small snippet with React.But this.state is not working in ES6 ReactJs.Help me what I am missing!!

JS without ES6:

```
 var App = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {value:''};
      },

      handleClick: function(e){
        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.value);//getting value here
      },
      render: function() {
        return(
          <div>
            Hello {this.props.name}
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
            {this.state.value}// no value
          </div>);
      }
    });
    React.render(<App name="Praveen" />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This case is working fine. [Jsbin code](https://jsbin.com/gunigawedo/edit?html,js,console,output)

JS with ES6:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={value:''};
  }
  handleClick(e){
    this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.value);//getting value here
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
        {this.state.value}// no value
      </div>);
  }
}
React.render(<App name="Praveen" />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

In this case whenever I am setting this.setState() render function is not called. [Jsbin code](https://jsbin.com/gunigawedo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React in ES6 removed auto binding of `this` which means that functions declared on a class that extends `React.Component` must either `.bind(this)` explicitly or use arrow function syntax.

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

or

```
class App extends React.Component {
   handleClick = (e) => {}
}
```

Comment: +1 There's a bit of danger using the second solution because it doesn't attach the function to the prototype. If the component were used many times, memory consumption could become an issue. Other than that, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, it is recommended to do the `bind`ing in the constructor instead so that the binding only happens upon initialization instead of on every `render`.

Read more about event handlers on React docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {value:''};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({value:e.target.value}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.value); // Updated value here
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
        {this.state.value}// no value
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this.setState({value:e.target.value});console.log(this.state.value);
    


//here you are not sure the this.state.value will reflect your new value e.target.value.

Because setValue is "async"

Comment: Great point. Updated the code to do that. Note that the answer was written very long ago (: